# Is this bad habit in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Ive used

```
const location = useLocation()
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
const productId = searchParams.get('productId')
```

to get the productId from the params. Is this a bad habit, any downsides? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: The way you use it is great. Just know that `useLocation` hook is not available on server-side rendering

Comment: Looks fine. You may want to memoize, if you expect url to change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's `react-router-dom`, you can use it's api:

```
const params = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useParams` hook of react :

```
const params = useParams();
```

but your code is ok